# requirejs: can I require a global runtime var?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm using requirejs in a somewhat special JS environment where an application provides a global singleton (I cannot change this fact, this isn't running in a typical browser environment). I am writing a sort of JS SDK for this application and want to provide various modules that use this global.

Can I wrap that global in a module somehow in order to require it from my modules? Something like

```
define([the_global_application], function(app)
```

Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to define it.

```
// mysingletonapp.js
// define the module for our global var
define(['list', 'any', 'dependency', 'here'], function (l, a, d, h) {
  return yourGlobalVariable;
});
```

(I don't think you'll have dependencies in there, since you're just wrapping a global `var`)

The you can use that module as usual:

```
require(['mysingletonapp'], function (app) {
  // do something cool
});
```

---

<s>If you want to skip all this, you can use the [`shim` property of RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim). You would just need to add this to your options file:</s>

```
...
shim: {
        'globalApplication': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'], // again, you should not need them
            exports: 'yourGlobalVar'
        }
}
...
```

`shim`s wrap libraries that don't support AMD, so to have this setting work, you would need a js for `globalApplication`. This isn't your case.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro! Pretty straightforward I guess but I didn't think of it. I had to create the dummy module-file though - if you use the shim config for that requirejs will search for the file globalApplication.js in your baseUrl, unless I did something wrong.